# Binding value to title not working on Tooltip

Tags: javascript, vue.js, tooltip, bootstrap-5

I'm working with `Vue3`, `Bootstrap 5.2` and `VueX`. I have a number of `tooltips` that should be language dependent. Now I want to change my `title` based on a variable from my store.

Unfortunately, the `tooltip` no longer works properly. The hover effect is only standard.

But if I insert a `title` manually, everything works perfectly.

How can I handle this? Thank You!

***App.vue***

```
mounted() {
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".tooltip-element")).forEach(
    (tooltipNode) => new Tooltip(tooltipNode)
  );
}
```

***Component.vue***

```
<template>
//this works fine
<button
  class="btn btn-success col-12 tooltip-element"
  data-bs-placement="right"
  title="testTooltip entered in manually"
>
  Test1
</button>

//this is not working
<button
  class="btn btn-success col-12 tooltip-element"
  data-bs-placement="right"
  :title="testTooltip"
>
  Test2
</button>
</template>

<script>
  data() {
    return {
      testTooltip: "This is the testTooltip",
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: What is `testTooltip`? And what does `new Tooltip(node)` do? You are doing 2 separate things which might overwrite each other

Comment: added ```script```. hopefully it's clear now..

Comment: new Tooltip(node) is just enabling the tooltip from Bootstrap.

Comment: If you remove the code inside `mounted`, does it work?

Comment: Is the `title` attribute correctly set on your button in the DOM inspector?